# NE555 varying PWM not working

Tags: pwm, fan, 555

I'm building a fan controller based on an NE555 with varying PWM.
Unfortunately the fan is continuously blowing at full speed no matter the potentiometer position.

I based the circuit [on this simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCCsB0AM8MUgLAUwLQA5wGY4E4B2ZMSHAJjFkzEwDYI7kRCpYoMwwAoAYxHKQ6A5O0HDyhciHZ58GfCDrQ6OHPByEa%20OlNiLYcWDwDmAoQKnmJmbO1jcASiGTJsTF25AUZv0eGl7GWhIbjA6SG9MZh0XeBBY4S5ofFTyCMJCVWQI8mRuAHdPd2ZIMGkPByKyitLygLtuACclCzB8CotxX1J4bjM3MQtBy0CZMOIlagE81ptsCCoEYMjHVABnAEt1gBcAQwA7XlRCqHrw9gikuntTq-AbufAO8YATKexyWyhHr8-wAByJDc3HeQjEsxun1m0jAQLAIOqv1m4Os4yRQ2EqL%206J%20mKgrjRVQJzG6kEJ6mYxPJzEp3kg0jpxJw0WejIZbNxOA57XZ0nIs2ZHIFtNZIq5wtm3MZsCpp2lnO6vNxSpe3TytyKLOY5WwFHYuvGLXQXkNJpKvnICCcIHNSmYdp8QX8kSChlCACNbeQcA6xuRYsyrQ0el9xgAPW0IxR0bBYHAsCA64QABQA6gBZAA66xTmwO3CtrHQHjNsUNzHTGdOdsNBrDxNrYZLOobhdgxdNWVt5e7zAAKgBBADCAAl%20i5PlYvDjNbaZ9Op4F252lz2JNOQABxAEAERX8%20hDti4srAHk0wBRRw2mezU0vZ313z2EI1u-MD8R72wSLfeMJEmDwgCmACuAA24HoKBAAOOb5lsryoDmABmhzcJG6BWoo6D1FhxaKKSzAAGKHDmyDoDB%20Y5gAFqgexIU03AAPa%20E6cSpOAr7wHQgiWmxLHeLIYwkLAWLBIgRBXHxEAyt43BAA) and can't figure out why it's not behaving the same way.

[image]

Comment: What is the part number of the chip you're using?  Driving the threshold & trigger inputs of a 555 from the output is only reliable if you're using one of the CMOS versions -- there's a good chance that a TTL version won't pull the output voltage high enough.

Comment: I believe that it should work as drawn. Your implementation may be at fault.

Comment: @TimWescott Thanks! Part number is: NE555DR, I am using this version [link](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Timers-Clock-Oscillators_UMW-Youtai-Semiconductor-Co-Ltd-NE555DR_C695838.html)

Comment: Also measuring the Voltage between Out-GND it stays at 12.2V

Comment: the fan PWM input may already have a pullup resistor

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit being the potentiometer, which got a different polarity than a previous one I used.